# Is there an IOS API that wraps the google 'distance between two locations' API?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, mapkit, google-api

Is there an IOS API that wraps the google 'distance between two locations' API?

That is, is there an apple IOS SDK method that one could call to use this google api at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/distancematrix/, or do you have to call the google API natively so to speak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no native iOS API for this, so you'll need to call the Google service directly.

Comment: thanks - do you know if there is a well know/popular 3rd party IOS library that people use here I should know about?  Or is it knock it up yourself from the ground level in objective-c?

Comment: I don't know of any wrappers for the Google APIs specifically, but there are frameworks to make it easier to work with REST-style APIs, such as [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).